# Magento 2 Bulk endpoint fails

Tags: product, magento2, endpoint, bulk

I try to make a bulk of a product in Magento2 as specified in the "Bulk Endpoints" web page from Adobe:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/bulk-endpoints/

url:
`myserver/async/bulk/V1/products/`

body:

```
[{
    "product": {
        "sku": "VBP_001",
        "extension_attributes": {
                "stock_item": {
                        "qty": "44",
                        "is_in_stock": true
                }
        }
    } }, {
    "product": {
        "sku": "VBP_002",
        "extension_attributes": {
                "stock_item": {
                        "qty": "55",
                        "is_in_stock": true
                }
        }
    } 
}]
```

I already installed and configured RabbitMQ as explained at:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/rabbitmq.html

Instead of retrieving an ok Json or an error Json, I get an error in html from the main site.